# process and signal assignment

Tags: vhdl

I have the above code segment. I am a bit confused, so can one help me ?

```
 wait until rising_edge ( clk ) ;
      sig_a <= sig_x and sig_y ;
      sig_b <= sig_a ;
```

Does sig_b use new value of sig_a ?

Answer (score 3):

Both events happen simultaneously, so `sig_a` gets a new value while `sig_b` does. In practice this is often done with cascading flip-flops, which are all clocked by the same edge, like in **shift registers**. This isn't a problem because the delay between the input and the output, so the input will take the old value of the previous output before it changes value.

Answer (score 1):

One of the tricky things about HDL is that assignment statements occur simultaneously. You could re-order the two `sig_a` and `sig_b` statements and the result would be the same.

The synthesizer will create two flip-flops for storing both `sig_a` and `sig_b`. The output of `sig_x AND sig_y` will be connected to the data input of the `sig_a` flip-flop, and the output of the `sig_a` flip-flop will feed into the data input of the `sig_b` flip-flop.

As a result, `sig_b` will store the old value of `sig_a` on the positive clock edge.

Answer (score 0):

No, `sig_b` gets the value of `sig_a` at the start of the process.

`<=` means "schedule an update to the signal", but it will not be updated until some simulation time passes.

(That amount of time could be 0 ns:

```
wait until rising_edge ( clk ) ;
sig_a <= sig_x and sig_y ;
wait for 0 ns;
sig_b <= sig_a ; -- sig_b now gets "sig_x and sig_y" from sig_a
```

But that'll not synthesise...)